# Exception handling doesn't avoid error

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's a snippet of the config file:

```
[{u'sequenceNumber': 10, u'text': u'--- 10-999 are broad permits'},
 {u'action': u'permit',
  u'counterData': {},
  u'log': False,
  u'payload': {u'payload': []},
  u'ruleFilter': {u'destination': {u'ip': u'0.0.0.0', u'mask': 0},
                  u'dscp': {u'match': False, u'value': 0},
                  u'dstPort': {u'maxPorts': 10,
                               u'oper': u'any',
                               u'ports': []},
                  u'established': False,
                  u'fragments': False,
                  u'gre': {u'protoMask': 0, u'protocol': 0},
                  u'gtp': {u'teid': 0, u'teidMask': 0},
                  u'icmp': {u'code': 65535, u'type': 65535},
                  u'nvgre': {u'protoMask': 0,
                             u'protocol': 0,
                             u'tni': 0,
                             u'tniMask': 0},
                  u'protocol': 2,
                  u'source': {u'ip': u'0.0.0.0', u'mask': 0},
                  u'srcPort': {u'maxPorts': 10,
                               u'oper': u'any',
                               u'ports': []},
                  u'standard': False,
                  u'tcpFlags': 0,
                  u'tracked': False,
                  u'ttl': {u'oper': u'any', u'value': 0},
                  u'userL4': {u'pattern': 0, u'patternMask': 0},
                  u'vlan': {u'id': 0,
                            u'innerId': 0,
                            u'innerMask': 0,
                            u'mask': 0},
                  u'vxlan': {u'vni': 0, u'vniMask': 0, u'vxlanValid': False}},
  u'sequenceNumber': 20,
  u'text': u'permit igmp any any'},
```

Snippet of code with problem.
Hereby, I'm trying to run through loop with `KeyError` and `NameError` handlers as not all lines in input have a value of 'src_mk'.

```
for seq in acl:
    try:
        src_mk = seq['ruleFilter']['source']['mask']
    except (KeyError, NameError):
        pass
    print src_mk
```

I'm getting a `NameError - name not defined`. I tired handling exception separately but it didn't work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
NameError: name 'src_mk' is not defined
```

Comment: `print src_mk` is after your `try` - so I'm not sure how you tried handling this exception

Comment: Where are you expecting a `NameError`?

Comment: What are you expecting `src_mk` to be in case a `KeyError` happens?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the variable outside the `try-except` block beforehand. See in the comments section [@Daniel Roseman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935658/python-error-handling-exception#comment72968856_42935704) for WHY your code doesn't work

Something in this lines should work:

```
for seq in acl:
    src_mk = None

    try:
        src_mk = seq['ruleFilter']['source']['mask']
    except (KeyError,NameError):
        pass

    print src_mk # Note that if it is None it means there was an exception
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: The solution is right, but the explanation is not. Python doesn't have block scope; the error is happening because the exception is being triggered, so the assignment is never reached. If the exception wasn't raised, the code would work and the variable would be visible outside the block.

Comment: You should really incorporate that comment into your answer to make it complete.